# Where can I download ECI resource adapter (cicseci.rar). Unable to find out it in IBM portal

Tags: java, websphere-liberty, mainframe, rar, jca

I want to use JCA(Java connector architecture) and get data from Mainframe system using IBM provided Resource adapter(.rar) file.  I could not find out this file in IBM portal.  Since it is an old way of connecting from Java to Mainframe, it may not available.  Please help me to find out.

I'm looking for IBM provided ECI resource adapter (cicseci.rar) file.  This file to be deployed in WAS server along with my client side code to establish the connection between Java and IBM mainframe system

Answer (score 2):

[CICS Transaction Gateway (CICS TG) SDK Downloads](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/6217349) which says (in part)

> The CICS TG SDK contains all the CICS TG JARs, RARs, shared libraries, headers, libs, and schemas that are needed to write, compile, and ship a CICS TG application for any supported release of CICS TG. The SDK is designed to provide everything that is required to write a client application, implementing one of the exits, processing CICS TG statistics, and creating JSON web services.

There is an archive of an archive in the download there, and within said archive you can find `cicstgsdk\api\jee\runtime\managed\cicseci.rar`

You may also find [Choosing the correct CICS TG Resource Adapter to deploy in WebSphere Application Server](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/choosing-correct-cics-tg-resource-adapter-deploy-websphere-application-server) helpful.

[image: CICS TG Zip File with cicseci.rar circled]